# how to open file dialog for upload when I click to my custom command in elfinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, elfinder

please help me. I am using elfinder, and I have a problem.

I want to open 'Open Dialog Box' (for upload) when I click to my custom Command. I want to implement my custom upload, how to do this?

this is my code :

```
$().ready(function() {
//   elFinder.prototype.i18.en.messages['cmdeditimage'] = 'Edit Image';          
//    elFinder.prototype.i18.de.messages['cmdeditimage'] = 'Bild bearbeiten';
      elFinder.prototype._options.commands.push('My_command');
      elFinder.prototype.commands.My_command = function() {
        this.exec = function(hashes) {
          //request from server
        }
        this.getstate = function() {
            //return 0 to enable, -1 to disable icon access
            return 0;
        }
    }

    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        resizable: false,
        lang: 'en',             // language (OPTIONAL)
        url : 'assets/elfinder/php/connector.php',  //connector URL
        width:'100%',
        uiOptions : {
            // toolbar configuration
            toolbar : [
                ['back', 'forward'],
                ['reload'],
                ['home', 'up'],
                ['mkdir', 'mkfile', 'upload'],
                ['open', 'download', 'getfile'],
                ['info'],
                ['quicklook'],
                ['copy', 'cut', 'paste'],
                ['rm'],
                ['duplicate', 'rename', 'edit', 'resize'],
                ['extract', 'archive'],
                ['search'],
                ['view'],
                ['help'],
                ['My_command']
            ]

            // directories tree options
        }
    }).elfinder('instance');
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post  any source and/or link?

Comment: What does that mean?
What's your Custom Command is? Is it a button or a link or just a heading tag or what it is?

Comment: that means my button in elfinder tools.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your issue. If you want a modal dialog just add that code inside `this.exec = function(hashes) {`. If you're asking about a modal dialog I suggest [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).